# Is this a more unequivocal way to make an analytic v synthetic distinction?

Tags: quine, logical-positivism, analytic-synthetic-divide, carnap

**NEW UPDATE:** An analytic expression x is redefined as any expression of language verified as completely true (or false) entirely on the basis that x (or ~x) is derived by applying truth preserving operations to other expressions of language axioms.

> An axiom is a proposition regarded as self-evidently true without
> proof. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Axiom.html

A text based artificial intelligence would have to rely on an axiomatic model of the world so that it would have the same basis as human minds. Each of the elements of this model precisely meet the rewritten definition of analytic.

**Is the above an unequivocal way to make an analytic v synthetic distinction, that would address Quine's objections?**

**PRIOR POST**

> “Analytic” sentences, such as “Pediatricians are doctors,” have
> historically been characterized as ones that are true by virtue of the
> meanings of their words alone and/or can be known to be so solely by
> knowing those meanings. They are contrasted with more usual
> “synthetic” sentences, such as “Pediatricians are rich,” (knowledge
> of) whose truth depends also upon (knowledge of) the worldly fortunes
> of pediatricians.
> https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/analytic-synthetic/

**I am taking the above definition to mean that analytic truth is simply a body of semantic tautologies within a model of the world so the definition of analytic seems to remain the same.**

**This seems at least somewhat consistent with Quine's holism where the model of the world is construed as Quine's "whole theory"**

> In philosophy of science, confirmation holism, also called
> epistemological holism, is the view that no individual statement can
> be confirmed or disconfirmed by an empirical test, but rather that
> only a set of statements (a whole theory) can be so.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_holism

"Dogs are animals" would be formalized as a relation between finite strings specifying a relation between semantic categories DOGS ⊆ ANIMALS.

From the above we divide off synthetic as: **Synthetic truth [new]** is the set of expressions of language that cannot be verified as true entirely ***within a model of the world*** and additionally require sense data from the sense organs: **{Example: There is a dog in my living room right now}**

**Quine's definition of the analytic v Synthetic distinction:**
"truths which are analytic, or grounded in meanings independently of matters of fact, and truth which are synthetic, or grounded in fact."
[**Two Dogmas of Empiricism
Willard Van Orman Quine**](http://www.ditext.com/quine/quine.html)

The expression: "dogs are animals" would seem to be synthetic under the Quine definition, because it is a fact that dogs are animals. Under the revised definitions facts of the world are encoded as natural language axioms. This constructs a model of the world. Thus {dogs are animals} becomes analytical.

When analytic truth is verified entirely on the basis of its meanings then it remains true in ***the model of the world*** even if untrue within the actual world.

One thing that is useful about this distinction is this definition of analytic draws a sharp boundary between what a text based AI mind could and could not do.

Comment: The definitions you give for analytic and synthetic are not correct. What you gave are (more or less) the definitions of a priori and a posteriori. Quine's definitions are correct. Whether analytic is the same as a priori and synthetic is the same as a posteriori is a matter of some controversy in philosophy.

Comment: @DavidGudeman the point is that I am overriding and replacing the standard definitions to in an attempt to address Quine's objections to the original standard definitions. **I used your feedback to make my question this much more clear.**

Comment: @polcott What counts as a "sense organ"? Also, what do we make of the statement "a triangle has 3 sides"? Is that an analytic or synthetic under your definitions? Finally, when you say "'dogs are animals' is a fact", what counts as a "fact"?

Comment: @Frank the typical five senses: Sight, Sound, Smell, Taste, and Touch are sense data from the sense organs. A triangle has three sides is true by definition, thus analytical. Everthing that is true by definition is a fact.

Comment: @polcott Is there any organ that perceive the triangle when it's just in my mind?

Comment: @Frank That triangles are defined to have three sides make this analytical no matter what else. That you can also see that triangles have three sides has no effect on whether this is analytical or not.

Comment: @polcott You say that analytic truths are "stipulated to be true". What is the stipulation mechanism? In "dogs are animals", there seems to be contingent part of the definition that's settled by observation of nature?

Comment: @Frank The system has told me too many comments.  The only way that we know that cats are animals and not some kind of ten sort office building is that it is stipulated that cats are animals.  **Analytic True [new] is always relations between finite text strings as defined above**

Comment: Your re-definitions do not address Quine's objections and would not work for Carnap's purposes, which is what the point of Quine's objections was. Carnap and Quine were not concerned with "analytic" in a specific language, where one is free to stipulate as they please, he was asking for a general explication of "analytic in L", where the language L is a *variable*. In other words, for spelling out the *underlying idea* that supposedly guides "stipulation" of some expressions as analytic and others not in Carnap's "linguistic frameworks". Quine argued that no  satisfactory explication exists.

Comment: @Conifold https://liarparadox.org/Meaning_Postulates_Rudolf_Carnap_1952.pdf Carnap defined the basis of Montague Grammar with his Meaning Postulates. Yes I usually say: "in L" I tried to keep is a little simpler. I will update this now. Stipulated relations between finite strings in language L seems to be a good basis. That is the only way that we know that "cats are animal" is true when encoded in English.

Comment: Those are meaning *postulates*, i.e. conditions that the explication of "analytic" is supposed to satisfy. Quine's point was that there is no cogent concept of "analytic in L" satisfying these conditions.

Comment: @Conifold Since I can see some of the details of how to do "analytic in L" I don't understand what he could mean. L could be FOL. L could be PA.

Comment: L could be anything coherent. What Carnap needs for his paradigm of linguistic frameworks is to explain how *he* will identify analytic expressions in *any* language someone *else* (scientists, say) comes up with. Those do not come with analytic 'stipulations', *he* needs to discriminate what is "analytic" there and what isn't based on some consistent rule. "Grounded in meanings independently of matters of fact" seemed like such a rule. Until Quine picked it apart.

Comment: @Conifold I might try to post a question about something related so I’m gauging the waters; can grounding come from the stipulation, as in the stipulation is what grounds what’s analytic for any language. What I have in mind is Plato, stipulating mathematics is not philosophical understanding, rather stipulated to be as if its starting hypothesis were first principles, then analytic truths  are proved. I think grounding can’t come without matters of fact, but intentional stipulation  can provide the facts. Analytic truths then are restrained within the language, and are not “understanding”.

Comment: @JKusin Nothing forces languages into volunteering stipulations for the "first principles" and "facts". Quine's holism holds, for example, that everything is synthetic, all "principles" are subject to revision, and all "facts" are theory-laden. And even if they do stipulate, what's to stop it from being on arbitrary whim? I do not think analytic as intended can come from stipulations, those may reflect analytic/synthetic just as well as something else entirely. We might as well dispense with the concept, many languages simply lack the dichotomic structure it presupposes, or restrict its use.

Comment: @Conifold "Quine's holism holds, for example, that everything is synthetic, all "principles" are subject to revision" That would seem to include the possibility that 3 > 2 (decimal digits) is mere a false opinion that has never been true.

Comment: @polcott If '3>2' is presumed to be an utterance, than clearly there was a time before such an utterance could be uttered by voices. If it's taken to be a mathematical fact, than the internal logic that validates the metaphysical necessity of it being a fact also came after such a logic could be constructed by minds. If it's taken to be a mathematical truth derived from foundations, then it isn't metaphysically necessary because it's truth is a function of the coherence of the axioms from the grounding system. That it is pragmatic to utter, intuit, or derive it is adequacy, not objective truth

Comment: @JD The value of the ratio of the diameter to the circumference of a circle was logically entailed by the concept of round prior to humans having the ability to count to five. Upon this basis we might conclude that the whole body of arithmetic was there waiting to be discovered. The mathematical mapping of these concepts to finite strings is necessarily simply stipulated and could not be otherwise.

Comment: @polcott I'm not sure how you would prove that metaphysical presumption. Prior to humans, there would simply be no logic as we know it. Logic is a property of systems which physically compute. There is simply no empirical evidence to show that logic floats around the universe like a ghost waiting to inhabit human heads upon birth.  (Tenuous notions of pancomputationalism notwithstanding.)

Comment: @JD Sure you can say that you don't believe me, yet there cannot possibly exist any counter example showing that PI is not logically entailed by round.

Comment: @polcott Indeed, I disagree, but again, in the spirit of fallibilism, strict criteria such as falsifiability while helpful for preventing underdetermination are not always logically necessary for determining adequacy of theory, and the relationship between round and pi while not metaphysically necessary does entail logical coherence, hence its utility. Possibility of existence is a sticky wicket, and is not determined by logical coherence, as in the case of surd beings such as mathematical i.

Comment: You simply are again weighting the logical coherence of analytical methods too heavily in a bid to construct an artificial class of language use, 'the analytical definition' not defensible in natural language.

Comment: For the record, I upvoted the question and did not downvote the answer. But I think it's fair to say that this post has generously allowed for discussion and falls closer to the notion of original philosophy at this point which would be fair grounds for closure, though I won't vote such except to be the fifth man.

Comment: @JD It seems to be crucially important to derive some formal notion of true(L, x) otherwise many terrible things could occur. That we cannot even do this for the body of semantic tautologies seems woefully inadequate.

Comment: Well, how about true(L,x,t) : t := (coherent, correspondent, deflationary, pragmatic) etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145638/discussion-between-polcott-and-j-d).

Answer (score 4):

Your proposed definitions would not address Quine's objections at all. For one thing, Quine is just as opposed to the concept of *a priori* knowledge as he is to analytic truth. For another, he rejects the claim that there can be truth by convention: this is the subject of his paper of that name.

Facts are not created by stipulation. With the exception of some special terminology that is introduced within scientific and technical disciplines, words have natural meanings. Nobody stipulates what they mean. Compilers of dictionaries are not in the business of stipulating meanings either; rather, they are in the business of documenting how the speakers of a language use the words it contains.

The proposition that dogs are animals is not true by stipulation and is not analytic. There are good empirical reasons to believe that dogs are animals. We observe that they reproduce, grow, die, eat, excrete, respire, move around, and interact with their environment. We classify dogs as animals for this reason, not as the result of an arbitrary stipulation.

Quine would say that "dogs are animals" is deeply entrenched in our web of belief and well protected from revision in the light of experience, but not immune to revision. Biologists can and do make revisions to the classification of living things, and they do so for empirical reasons. Not so long ago it was believed that giant pandas were raccoons, but after their DNA was sequenced it was discovered that they are in fact bears. Similarly, fungi were once classified as plants but they are now considered to be a kingdom in their own right. These classifications are neither analytic nor *a priori* but based on empirical facts, which are in turn based on observation.

One of the most foolish mistakes that beginners in philosophy make is to suppose that truths are created by definitions or by stipulations. At the end of the day definitions are redundant: they are just a convenient shorthand. What makes propositions true is that they form part of our best scientific theories. And for Quine, the truth of a proposition (or sentence, as he prefers) cannot be assessed on a sentence-by-sentence basis but by consideration of the entire theory or chunk of beliefs of which the sentence is a part. This is why, for Quine, no sentence is analytic. A sentence inherits empirical content from the empirical theory of which it is a part.

Comment: "Facts are not created by stipulation." Facts and tautologies are encoded in language as stipulated relations between finite strings. Disagreeing with these stipulated relations is the same as disagreeing with a tautology, necessarily incorrect. The only way that we know that dogs are animals and not ten story office buildings is stipulated relations between finite strings that encode facts.

Comment: Facts are different from tautologies and are not true by stipulation. Two people may disagree about whether a proposition is true and this does not entail that one of them is using the language incorrectly. A person may change their mind about whether a proposition is true and this does not entail that they previously misunderstood the language. All beliefs about propositions are open to revision in the light of empirical experience...

Comment: And even tautologies are not stipulations. In the logical sense of the term, tautologies exist only in formal systems and not in natural language. The tautologies of classical logic are different from those of intuitionistic logic and from those of relevance logic, etc. Nobody stipulates that a given logic and its tautologies are correct and nobody is necessarily incorrect if they choose to use a different logic.

Comment: " In the logical sense of the term, tautologies exist only in formal systems and not in natural language."  That would mean that the expression: "existence exists" is possibly a misconception and the truth is that actually nothing has ever existed. **Any expression of formal or natural language such that its negation is unsatisfiable seems to sum it up.** (this excludes self-contradictory expressions that are necessarily not truth bearers).

Comment: But there are lots of formal systems and they differ. And people disagree about lots of things without misunderstanding each other. As to the sentence "existence exists" I have no idea what that means. It does not seem to me to parse correctly. If it means, "the universe is non-empty" then I would agree that is true, but not that its negation is unsatisfiable.

Comment: Try and explain why you cannot prove that you yourself don't exist and you will see that there are natural language tautologies. **A tautology would seem to be any expression of natural or formal language that is not contradictory and having an unsatisfiable negation.**

Comment: "The proposition that dogs are animals is not true by stipulation and is not analytic" The only way that we know that "dogs are animals" (in English) is a relation between words that we know to be true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145485/discussion-between-bumble-and-polcott).

Comment: The only way that the finite string "dog" acquires any semantic meaning is that this semantic meaning is assigned to the finite string otherwise the finite string "dog" remains utterly meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

> Analytic truth is the set of expressions of language that can be verified as completely true without any sense data from the sense organs: Example {Dogs are animals}

I think the inherent contradiction with the alternative definition prevented is that most people come to understand the use and mention of 'dog' and 'animal' by appealing to the senses [intuitionally (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuition/) and fundamentally. A dog is an often fluffy-to-touch, visibly four-legged, animal that smells peculiar when wet, and barks loudly. An animal is generally a moving, breathing, frequently visibly-legged thing with a bumpy backbone, laps up wet water, (insert additional sensory description here).

Thus, the determination of [natural kinds (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-kinds/) is inherently [folk psychological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk_psychology) precisely because it relies on the senses ot make sense of the world:

> Scientific disciplines frequently divide the particulars they study into kinds and theorize about those kinds. To say that a kind is natural is to say that it corresponds to a grouping that reflects **the structure of the natural world** rather than the interests and actions of human beings. We tend to assume that science is often successful in revealing these kinds; it is a corollary of scientific realism that when all goes well the classifications and taxonomies employed by science correspond to the real kinds in nature. (Emphasis mine)

That is, for most people "the structure of the natural world" is dictated by the senses rather than operational definitions, mathematical physics, psychometrics, etc. People make sense of the world initially through their senses and only develop a more language-like analytical capacity through extensive socialization and education.

This is presumably why the [analytic-synthetic distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic%E2%80%93synthetic_distinction) appeals to the explicit sentence that expresses the [proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition):

> **analytic proposition**: a proposition whose predicate concept is contained in its subject concept
> **synthetic proposition**: a proposition whose predicate concept is not contained in its subject concept but related

This "closeness" of subject to predicate is precisely a linguistic distinction because propositions themselves are adjacent to language use. From a [nominalist's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalism) perspective, linguistic labels are just a tool for describing and communicating experience, and all language, ultimately to be meaningful has to have some grounding in the senses, a perspective that begins with [British empiricism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empiricism#British_empiricism) and is defended contemporaneously by physicalists in various philosophical arguments such as van Fraasen's [constructive empiricism (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/constructive-empiricism/) and 2nd-generation cognitive science's [embodied cognition (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/embodied-cognition/).

Comment: What does it mean that a "proposition is _adjacent_ to language use"?

Comment: Propositions (if you believe they exist) and utterances/sentences obey dualism. A proposition is an imputed mental artifact, whereas an utterance is the concrete communication that conveys it. Synonymy and substitutativity in philosophy of language presumes that multiple utterances can have the same content (proposition). We can use use-mention to exemplify. 'Der Schnee ist weiß' and 'The snow is white' are two utterances with the same mental content and even the same decompositionality. 'Schnee' means 'snow', 'ist' means 'is', etc...

Comment: The nature of propositions is that they convey belief and desire generally, but given mind-body duality, we cannot directly inspect someone's propostions, their mental content. We can only infer the meaning from the statement or utterance. Such an act is interpretation, and interpretation, like translation and belief attribution more generally, is [underdetermined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermination). In a broad epistemological sense, we can only infer mental content of others through our subjective lens. This is related to the easy and hard problems of consciousness, which is to

Comment: @Frank provide explanations for why what appears to be regarding mind-body duality actually is.

Comment: Think of it is as ISO OSI.... propositions are application layer communications whereas sentences are physical layer communications.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question has prompted several objections it might have avoided if you had cast it in a different way. I sense from your own answer that what you were trying to do was draw a distinction between truths that could be recognised by AI without any sensory inputs and truths that could not. If you had made that the sole focus of your question, you would have got a more helpful response, I suspect. As it is, by conflating that objective with another of trying to dodge Quine's assertion that all statements are really synthetic, you have triggered a lot of antibodies.

Yes, you can if you wish develop your own idiosyncratic definition of analytic and synthetic, but that doesn't change the validity of Quine's position, since that was directed at the original position of the goalposts before your attempt to move them.

To put my point another way, you might have received a different response had you substituted 'an' for 'the' in the headline question.

Comment: ***It seems that Quine is saying that hardly anything is synthetic:*** In philosophy of science, confirmation holism, also called epistemological holism, is the view that no individual statement can be confirmed or disconfirmed by an empirical test, but rather that only a set of statements (a whole theory) can be so. It is attributed to Willard Van Orman Quine 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_holism  (I changed "the" to "an")

Comment: I am trying to unravel how these things can be coherently understood which may require them to be redefined to remove any incoherence. If we say that all analytical truth only exists within an abstract model of the world then this may be a totally coherent way of viewing it. This certainly seems consistent with the SEP definition of analytical: "true by virtue of the meanings of their words alone and/or can be known to be so solely by knowing those meanings."

Comment: I understand that, and it is fine. If you create a model of the world, in that model you can make stipulations such as cats are animals, and you can define analytical statement to be those that are true on the basis of the stipulations alone. That all seems consistent to me.

Comment: So I am thinking that this might be construed as a new and improved definition of analytical. It can be converted into a consistent formal system that is not incomplete and True(L, x) can be defined.

Comment: I think you are missing a point here, which is that it is your personal definition. Whether it is new I cannot say, since others might already have thought of it. Whether it is improved is a matter of opinion and perspective.

Comment: The point is that if there are problems with the original then it needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in my comment, what you are proposing to do is essentially to replace the analytic/synthetic distinction with the *a priori*/*a posteriori* distinction. Kant distinguished these two categories in the eighteenth century, and ever since, it has been controversial whether one pair can replace the other or not.

Kant claimed that the pairs are not identical; that there is synthetic *a priori* knowledge. He pointed to arithmetic as an example. You can know that 2+3=5 without examining objects in the real world to know if it's true, but most philosophers believe that 2+3=5 is not analytic. This is controversial, though; some philosophers called neo-Fregeans would say that is analytic.

Broadly, those who would say that your reduction is correct (that is, that you can replace the traditional analytic/synthetic distinction with *a priori*/*a posteriori* are called empiricists. Another example Kant gave to show that the two pairs are different is geometry. For example, it seems that we don't need to actually examine the real world to know that you can connect any two points with a line segment. Empiricists would generally disagree, and claim that this can only be known from experience.

Also, you go a little off the standard definition of *a posteriori* by referring to sense impressions. Aren't there things you can learn from experience that aren't directly related to sense impressions? For example, can't you be imagining a story in your head and decide that you don't like one of the characters, even though no sense impressions are involved? According to your definitions, this fact which you learned from experience would be known analytically, which doesn't seem right.

Incidentally, pretty much everyone would agree that "a dog is an animal" is analytic. It's practically a canonical example of an analytic sentence. To see this, ask whether you could ever empirically find a dog that isn't an animal. Obviously, you couldn't, because anything that isn't an animal would not count as a dog. Being an animal is part of what you mean by calling something a dog.

Comment: I will sum it up differently and more succinctly, **analytic truth** is defined as expressions of language that have been stipulated to be true (the whole set of facts) and expressions that are a semantic consequence of these expressions. This leaves **synthetic truth** as expressions of language requiring sense data from the sense organs to verify their truth.

Comment: @polcott Before "semantic consequence", maybe you could also consider "formal logic consequences", since formal logic is not supposed to add anything new to the starting point of the deduction.

Comment: @polcott, you are confusing things by continuing to refer to your definitions as definitions of analytic/synthetic when they aren't. They aren't conceptually identical to the standard definitions, and there is good reason to believe that they aren't practically equivalent either. If you want to be understood, you need to word things the way I did in my answer. Take the traditional definitions of analytic/synthetic and ask whether your new definitions have the same practical effect. This isn't redefining the existing concepts; it is asking whether a new pair of concepts is equivalent.

Comment: @Frank I am implicitly referring to formalized semantics of formal or natural language both anchored in set theory.  I have the Semantic Necessity operator: ⊨□ as a replacement for logical implication. This guarantees semantic relevance.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I am not aiming for equivalence because sufficient equivalence would have the same ambiguity issues. New_Analytic is stipulated to mean any expression of language that can be determined to be true on the basis of relations between finite strings.

Comment: @polcott, fair enough, but don't word it is redefining the concept because once you do, then you no longer have a way to discuss the previous concept and compare it to the new one.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I explicitly renamed them as [new] so that they can be distinguished from [original] because of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I am defining analytic in the same way that the Logical positivists do, and merely adding a nuance of criteria to their same definition of synthetic.

**Logical positivist definitions**
Thus the logical positivists drew a new distinction, and, inheriting the terms from Kant, named it the "analytic-synthetic distinction".[7] They provided many different definitions, such as the following:

(1) analytic proposition: a proposition whose truth depends solely on the meaning of its terms

(2) analytic proposition: a proposition that is true (or false) by definition

(3) analytic proposition: a proposition that is made true (or false) solely by the conventions of language

(While the logical positivists believed that the only necessarily true propositions were analytic, they did not define "analytic proposition" as "necessarily true proposition" or "proposition that is true in all possible worlds".)

Synthetic propositions were then defined as: synthetic proposition: a proposition that is not analytic

## My intention was to unequivocally divide expressions of language into

(a) Those requiring sense data from the sense organs to verify their truth: "there is a dog in my living room right now". SYNTHETIC

(b) Those that can be verified as true on the basis of their relation to other expressions within a model of the world. "cats are animals" is stipulated to be true within a model of the world. ANALYTICAL

This division specifies the limits of a text based artificial intelligence that has no sense organs or sense data.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding your new proposal:** By applying truth-preserving operations you aren't able to distinguish *meanings* (intensions) - obviously, because *all* true sentences are equivalent (coextensive), although they don't have the same *meaning* (if we were able to specify what *meanings* are, of course, which Quine denies). This simply doesn't work.

Comment: I included that we can and do stipulate the meanings of terms and then derive the set of true or false expressions of language x or ~x by applying truth preserving operations to expressions comprised of these semantic meanings. The stipulated meanings of terms are like axioms and the expressions derived from them comprise the entire body of analytic expressions.

Comment: @polcott Then you beg the question against Quine.

Comment: Within my redefinition of {analytic} when Quine says that facts are synthetic he is simply wrong. That {dogs} <are> {animals} is an axiom anchored in the stipulated meaning of these terms.

Comment: @polcott But Quine asks if there is any good criterion of that. I don't see how your proposal resolves his issue.

Comment: Any expression of language that can be resolved as true or false entirely on the basis of other expressions of language that stipulate the meaning of its terms seems to be airtight to me. (Analytical expressions are resolved to true or false by pure analysis) Can you come of with a counter-example where this does not work?

Comment: @polcott Yes, this is airtight, because you're moving in circles. It is banal to define "other expressions of language that stipulate the meaning" in terms of analycity or vice-versa. The question is: how to escape the circle?

Comment: It never has been a circle it has always been a tree (directed acyclic graph) of knowledge. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science)

Comment: @polcott ??? How is that relevant to my objection?

Comment: You said that my reasoning circular and this is factually incorrect. My reasoning actually has the data structure of a tree, no loops involved what-so-ever. When the term {bachelor} is stipulated to derive all of its meaning from {adult} & {male} & {~married} then there is no circle involved.

Comment: @polcott Yes, analytic sentences are these sentences which can be derived from what Carnap called "meaning postulates". As I have already said, Quine's objection is regarding which sentences should be considered "meaning postulates". What do you not understand?

Comment: I am saying that anything that can be encoded using language can be a meaning postulate, when Quine disagrees (within my redefinition) then Quine is wrong.

Comment: @polcott Yes, that's correct. Quine would just say that thus the distinction becomes pointless, because it is merely aesthetic. We sometimes can say that we're augmenting our meaning postulates, in other cases that we're augmenting our beliefs, but this is no substantial difference. But if you want to insist on the distinction, then you surely can.

Comment: It is not a merely a belief that {dogs} <are> {animals}, in my system it is an axiom. The correct model of the actual world <is> this full set of axioms.

Comment: @polcott A sentence doesn't acquire any additional significance by being considered "an axiom". You can axiomatize the same theory in multiple ways. "Being an axiom" doesn't imply necessity in any ways, because it doesn't imply preservation across theory change (like analycity would). I don't know what you're talking about honestly.

Comment: Anyone that disagrees that {cats} <are> {animals} is necessarily and unequivocally incorrect.

Comment: @polcott Why are you using this odd notation? Anyway, you keep repeating your thesis, but you didn't provide any justification for it. You didn't even try to explain analycity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151300/discussion-between-polcott-and-abcga).